# Docker image with Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, docker, dockerfile, devops

I created a docker image with python and ruby. When my docker image was only with python it was working. Now the image was not working for some reason. Any hints will be useful.

```
FROM python:2.7
LABEL maintainer="author"
COPY ./testapp /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python init_db.py


FROM ruby:2.7.1
RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install inspec

EXPOSE 3111
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: `Now the image was not working` "not working" doesn't tell us much.  Are you getting errors?  What, specifically, is happening?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. The build was successful but my web app is not loading when I use this docker file.

Comment: @AdamSmooch Yes you can have multiple `FROM` statements in a Dockerfile.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

Comment: Missed the edit window - [erroneous] comment deleted 

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 5):

Docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) cannot be used to combine two images in this way. However, there are at least two alternatives:

**Build a custom image**

Use a single base image (e.g. python) and install any additional dependencies (e.g. ruby) on top of it. An additional dependency like ruby can be installed manually using `apt-get`:

```
# Use python as the base image
FROM python:2.7

# Install ruby
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ruby
```

**Use a pre-built image that includes your dependencies**

You can use a pre-built image that already includes python and ruby, e.g. [drwahl/python-ruby](https://hub.docker.com/r/drwahl/python-ruby).